# How task names are mapped in grunt?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I cannot understand how grunt matches tasks with  `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
        dist: {
            src: ['src/*.js'],
            dest: 'dest/all.js'
        }
    }

});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat']);
```

};

It's a valid config. But I don't know how grunt match **'concat'** to **'grunt-contrib-concat'**.
Does grunt trim the '*grunt-contrib-*' prefix to match '*concat*' to '*grunt-contrib-concat*'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we look inside [grunt-contrib-concat source code](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat/blob/master/tasks/concat.js):

```
grunt.registerMultiTask('concat', 'Concatenate files.', function() {
```

Looking inside [grunt creating tasks docs](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks), **the first argument passed into a task registration function is the name of the task**:

```
 grunt.registerMultiTask(taskName, [description, ] taskFunction)

 grunt.registerTask(taskName, [description, ] taskFunction)
```

#### Consclusion

- There is no "magic" names nor "grunt keywords"
- There is no difference between your custom tasks and task plugins ( even grunt-contrib.. )
- The **API** for creating tasks is simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

> **contrib-less, contrib-jade, contrib-concat ....** so **contrib** is just to signifies that these plugins are contributed by **Grunt community developers** and less, jade, concat indicate the modules which you want to work on your project as mentioned in **gruntfile.js**.

So when you say:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat')
```

It loads the mentioned module.

But in order to make it work when you fire **grunt**, you actually have to register it.

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat','jade','less']);
grunt.registerTask('test', ['concat','jade','less']);
grunt.registerTask('dist', ['concat','jade','less','uglify']);
```

So as you can see in **production** we may want to **uglify**, so we can register our task in by '**dist**'.

Comment: you want to tell me concat is wellknown word for grunt?

Comment: Yes jade,concat,less are all  like a keyword for grunt.

Comment: there are no "keywords" for grunt. just a task registration api

Comment: Yes in simple words the `task runner` reads the tasks such as `jade,concat,less ...` mentioned in `gruntfile.js`. But strictly speaking they are not the keywords. Just the community has defined specifications for it and we follow.